# My page scrolls horizontally on mobile

Tags: css, html

I just found out that my website is scrolling horizontally on mobile. However, I am not able to find out why this is happening.

The containers and body seem to have the correct width when I check it in my browser.

Any idea?

https://www.urban-zweirad.de

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: margsenjo Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is some extra margin on your header or navigation which is having more width than your body/container.

add `overflow-x:hidden` in body

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```

Comment: tried this, and it changed the behavior on desktop. however on my phone it still slides to the side (iPhone)

Comment: Just checked in the browser inspector that overflow-x:hidden is not added yet. maybe you have added on wrong file?

Comment: I removed it again because it didn't work. Just put it back on, still no success on mobile though.

Comment: When you put it then clear your mobile browser cache because safari/chrome will have the cache problem. so either you try safari private browsing mode or delete history/cache in your iPhone settings and check. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

it seems line number 204 from _pages.scss is creating issue

```
.teaser {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

try removing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your class named "main"

what you need to do is to add css property : overflow:hidden;

```
.main{
overflow:hidden
}
```

think this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this part of your `HTML`. @pons awnsered correct.

```
<div class="container-fluid center teaser" data-plim="495">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can you fix it? You could remove the `.row` class. As this is not neccessary because its a full width bootstrap col. And the `.container-fluid` allready  clearfixes the floats.

You also just could change the `CSS` of the `.teaser` class into:

```
.teaser {
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden; // This fixes the negative margin on the row to be hidden inside its parent.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to body tag

```
.body{
  ..
  ..

  width: calc(100% - 8px);
}
```